# CS0246: Missing an assembly reference - works locally, but not on webserver

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, assemblies, compiler-errors

I'm trying to implement a paymentgateway (Ewire, a danish payment gateway), and it works fine locally, but when I'm putting it online, it says I'm missing an assembly reference.

I am sure that I'm using all the assembly references I need, since it works offline, and I'm also sure that the public class is registered (it's in my masterpage's .cs.designer file).

Here's the error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'EwirePaymentDetails' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 25:     public partial class WebForm7 : System.Web.UI.Page
Line 26:     {
Line 27:         public EwirePaymentDetails paymentDetails;
Line 28: 
Line 29:         public void InitializePaymentDetailsSuccesOrFail()
```

Detailed Compiler output, if it's of any use:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe"  /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\assembly\dl3\f0e28bc3\008f3dbe_c834cb01\MySql.Data.Entity.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_z1chkizv.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\assembly\dl3\106b0db1\008f3dbe_c834cb01\MySql.Web.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\assembly\dl3\38a7fb7c\00745868_ae59cb01\antikaput.com.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\assembly\dl3\d44ffbd1\0035dbbb_c834cb01\MySql.Data.DLL" /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /win32res:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\brje7fur.res" /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701 /warnaserror-  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.9.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.13.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.6.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.0.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.15.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.5.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.3.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.11.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.12.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.8.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.2.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.14.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.1.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.7.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.16.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.4.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.10.cs"


Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2008 Compiler version 3.5.30729.4926
for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 3.5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.6.cs(137,60): warning CS0436: The type 'Antikaput.com.WebForm4' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.6.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'Antikaput.com.WebForm4' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\assembly\dl3\38a7fb7c\00745868_ae59cb01\antikaput.com.DLL'. Using the type defined in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.6.cs'.
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.6.cs(15,26): (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\assembly\dl3\38a7fb7c\00745868_ae59cb01\antikaput.com.DLL: (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.0.cs(130,66): warning CS0436: The type 'Antikaput.com.WebForm11' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.0.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'Antikaput.com.WebForm11' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\assembly\dl3\38a7fb7c\00745868_ae59cb01\antikaput.com.DLL'. Using the type defined in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.0.cs'.
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.0.cs(15,26): (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\assembly\dl3\38a7fb7c\00745868_ae59cb01\antikaput.com.DLL: (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.12.cs(529,61): warning CS0436: The type 'Antikaput.com.WebForm7' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.13.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'Antikaput.com.WebForm7' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\assembly\dl3\38a7fb7c\00745868_ae59cb01\antikaput.com.DLL'. Using the type defined in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.13.cs'.
\\10.0.3.32\home\antikaput.com\public_html\alpha\minside.aspx.cs(25,26): (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\assembly\dl3\38a7fb7c\00745868_ae59cb01\antikaput.com.DLL: (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.8.cs(165,58): warning CS0436: The type 'Antikaput.com.WebForm8' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.9.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'Antikaput.com.WebForm8' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\assembly\dl3\38a7fb7c\00745868_ae59cb01\antikaput.com.DLL'. Using the type defined in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.9.cs'.
\\10.0.3.32\home\antikaput.com\public_html\alpha\soeg.aspx.cs(20,26): (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\assembly\dl3\38a7fb7c\00745868_ae59cb01\antikaput.com.DLL: (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.2.cs(130,60): warning CS0436: The type 'Antikaput.com.WebForm5' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.3.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'Antikaput.com.WebForm5' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\assembly\dl3\38a7fb7c\00745868_ae59cb01\antikaput.com.DLL'. Using the type defined in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.3.cs'.
\\10.0.3.32\home\antikaput.com\public_html\alpha\logout.aspx.cs(10,26): (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\assembly\dl3\38a7fb7c\00745868_ae59cb01\antikaput.com.DLL: (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.14.cs(130,61): warning CS0436: The type 'Antikaput.com.WebForm12' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.15.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'Antikaput.com.WebForm12' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\assembly\dl3\38a7fb7c\00745868_ae59cb01\antikaput.com.DLL'. Using the type defined in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.15.cs'.
\\10.0.3.32\home\antikaput.com\public_html\alpha\faktura.aspx.cs(10,26): (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\assembly\dl3\38a7fb7c\00745868_ae59cb01\antikaput.com.DLL: (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.4.cs(144,72): warning CS0436: The type 'Antikaput.com.WebForm6' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.5.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'Antikaput.com.WebForm6' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\assembly\dl3\38a7fb7c\00745868_ae59cb01\antikaput.com.DLL'. Using the type defined in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.5.cs'.
\\10.0.3.32\home\antikaput.com\public_html\alpha\handelsbetingelser.aspx.cs(10,26): (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\assembly\dl3\38a7fb7c\00745868_ae59cb01\antikaput.com.DLL: (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.10.cs(172,61): warning CS0436: The type 'Antikaput.com.WebForm10' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.11.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'Antikaput.com.WebForm10' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\assembly\dl3\38a7fb7c\00745868_ae59cb01\antikaput.com.DLL'. Using the type defined in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\App_Web_brje7fur.11.cs'.
\\10.0.3.32\home\antikaput.com\public_html\alpha\payment.aspx.cs(16,26): (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7803be99\b2680a1e\assembly\dl3\38a7fb7c\00745868_ae59cb01\antikaput.com.DLL: (Location of symbol related to previous warning)
\\10.0.3.32\home\antikaput.com\public_html\alpha\minside.aspx.cs(27,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'EwirePaymentDetails' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

So is this a local server problem, or am I missing something?

I am sure the dll's in my \bin folder is up to date as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the error is due to Ewire dll not being present on the server. Try to right click on that dll reference and set **Copy Local** to true, so that it gets copied to the bin folder.

Comment: Your answer led me on the right track - apparently I hadn't updated the dll's in the parent folders \bin, which caused the error :)